# Let $a$ be a set accumulation point $X$. Show that there is either an increasing sequence, or a decreasing sequence of...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, problem-solving

> Let $a$ be a set accumulation point $X$. Show that there is either an increasing sequence, or a decreasing sequence of points $x_n \in X$ with $lim_{x_n}=a$.

Let $A_n = (a -\frac{1}{n}, a)$ and $B_n = (a, a +\frac{1}{n})$, as $a \in A'$ then one of these sets has infinite elements of $A$, if $A_n$ is infinite we can define $(x_n)$ increasing with $lim x_n = a$ otherwise we define $(y_n)$ decreasing, both with limit $a$.

That's right? is enough?

Thanks.

Comment: What you have holds the correct ideas, I think. However, I think the argument needs to be made clearer (example: why do you know $A_n$ or $B_n$ have infinitely many elements? How do you know such a sequence exists just because $A_n$ has infinitely many points of $X$?)

Comment: @Clayton I dont think its correct, see my answer.

Comment: Your error:  Suppose it is true that  $(a-\frac1n,a)\cap X$ is nonempty for all $n$; then  it is possible to select $x_n\in  (a-\frac1n,a)\cap X$ for each $n$.  But that sequence may "look like" it is increasing, but it need not be.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Seems like I misread your approach a bit, you seem to want to keep picking elements $x_{n}$ from $(a_{n}-1/n, a)\cap X$(Assuming WLOG it’s always non empty), but that doesn’t necessarily give you an increasing sequence! (Thanks to BS Thomson, pointing for out I misread your argument!) What you can do to fix this is to keep picking increasing elements and now this is fixed. Also note the use of the axiom of (countable) choice.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Thanks please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Correct.  One way is inductively;  pick $x_1\in (a-1,a)\cap X$ and $x_{n+1} \geq a-\frac1n$ in $(x_n,a)\cap X$.

Comment: Correct. That’s why I said it holds the correct ideas but needs more clarity. See my comment above.